# Python - [Errno 13] Permission denied. Not able to open the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, csv, spyder

I'm getting IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied and I don't know what is wrong wit this code.

I'm trying to read a file given an absolute path

```
with open(r"E:\Paper\codedata.tsv", 'r+') as temp_f:

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "E:\Paper\code.py", line 18, in <module>
    with open(r"E:\Paper\codedata.tsv", 'r') as temp_f:
```

What I have tried so far:

1. Changed file permissions. I am using Windows 10
2. Windows is upto Date
3. Working in Anaconda spyder. Tried opening spyder in admin and running the code
4. Changed directory of data to different path

I am using Python 3.

Comment: did you try opening `cmd` as admin and running code from there?

Comment: Getting Same error!!